# html form elements

Tags: php, html, forms

i add elements like this.
i want this element to appear inside a div ..how do i do it..?

```
$form->addElement('text','first_name','First Name:');
```

Comment: Please don't bombard us with that many details.

Comment: what framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll just shoot into the dark and assume the following:

`$form->addElement()` will return some sort of class object representing an html element. therefor, create a div element, save it to a variable and add the text element (whatever that may be … `<input type="text" />`?) to it.

```
$div = $form->addElement('div');
$div->addElement('text','first_name','First Name:');
```

remember: i do not know what framework you are using, i'm just guessing here to give you some starting point